# search query in IE with php header location won't work

Tags: php, internet-explorer, header

I would appreciate your help again, because that damn IE is driving me crazy...

My problem -> I got a search field on my website and in Chrome, Safari, Mozilla you're able to type in a search query and press a button to do a search...works fine so far. You'll get redirected and you'll get a result.

BUT the damn IE is just not doing what it should. It opens up a new blank page (what's correct) and then it shows the same page u came from :-/

Here's my code...and as I said, works fine in all the other browsers!

HTML:

```
<form target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="searchbar" size="40" maxlength="40"> 
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="abc" value="Search now"
      formaction="php/abc.php" formmethod="get"> </form>
```

and abc.php:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['searchbar']))
{
$url = array(
    'Search now'=>'http://www.mywebsite.org/search?q=__keywords__');

header('Location:'.str_replace('__keywords__',preg_replace('/(\ )+/', '+', trim($_REQUEST['searchbar'])),$url[trim($_REQUEST['abc'])]));
die();
}
else
{
die();
}
?>
```

I'm still learning and trying to get better...so please don't jude me :)

Thx!

Comment: save the altered url you are using for the header location, then echo it out, impossible to debug the way you are doing it.

Comment: Could you explain it more detailed with code? Sorry...I'm still a newbie

Comment: I am not 100% sure but still you can try enabling output buffering and set 'ob_start()' at the start of your code **the very first** and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help...I've tried and tried...and the solution is pretty simple ;)

For all who will ever have the same problem:

Just add that piece of code to your submit input:

> input type="submit"
>       onclick="this.form.action='whatever.php';this.formsubmit();" name="abc" value="Search now"
>       formmethod="get">

Works in IE now!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Add your **action** attribute to your FORM tag. I'm not sure that **formaction** attribute is supported everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="php/abc.php">
    <input type="text" name="searchbar" size="40" maxlength="40"> 
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="abc" value="Search now"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Mhh..ok I tried that! But the problem that comes up now, is...I have different "Search now"-Buttons on there and they all use different php scripts. So if I put the form action "abc.php" at the top...I am only able to use the first button :-/ how can I fix this? if the next button should use... "xyz.php"?  Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: example of the code:
       `<form target="_blank">
        <input type="text" name="searchbar" size="40" maxlength="40"> 
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="abc" value="Search    now"
      formaction="php/abc.php" formmethod="get"> 
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="xyz" value="Search now"
      formaction="php/xyz.php" formmethod="get"> </form>`